# MySql CASE WHEN THEN needs WHERE too?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc, CASE colb
WHEN '6kHcnevOJOSU' THEN 0
WHEN 'g45ujP0td6nw' THEN 1
WHEN 'v83f15lALyFs' THEN 2
END AS sor FROM mytable
```

The 'sor' column is returned correctly, the problem is that the query returns all the rows, not just the ones where one of the cases match colb !
How can I have it to return only the matched rows ?

Do I need to add a WHERE ? But I always saw this syntax without it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need a `where` clause if you want to filter the results. Your current query will return `null` values for the last column for records that do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `where` clause:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc,
       (CASE colb WHEN '6kHcnevOJOSU' THEN 0 
                  WHEN 'g45ujP0td6nw' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'v83f15lALyFs' THEN 2
        END) as sor
FROM mytable t
WHERE colc IN (0, 1, 2);
```

Alternatively, you can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc,
       (CASE colb WHEN '6kHcnevOJOSU' THEN 0 
                  WHEN 'g45ujP0td6nw' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'v83f15lALyFs' THEN 2
        END) as sor
FROM mytable t
HAVING sor IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The second seems perfect !  I see that you replaced AS with parentesis, any difference ?

Comment: @Jackt . . . Actually, I usually put `CASE` in parentheses (easier to read) and always use `as ` for column aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Schema:

```
drop table if exists mytable;
create table mytable
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    cola int not null,
    colb varchar(20) not null,
    colc int not null
);
insert mytable (cola,colb,colc) values
(9,'6kHcnevOJOSU',1),
(3,'v83f15lALyFs',1),
(9,'frog',1),
(3,'g45ujP0td6nw',1);
```

Option 1:

```
SELECT cola, colb, colc, CASE colb
WHEN '6kHcnevOJOSU' THEN 0
WHEN 'g45ujP0td6nw' THEN 1
WHEN 'v83f15lALyFs' THEN 2
END AS sor FROM mytable
where colb in ('6kHcnevOJOSU','g45ujP0td6nw','v83f15lALyFs');
```

Option 2:

```
select cola,colb,colc,sor
from
(   SELECT cola, colb, colc, CASE colb
    WHEN '6kHcnevOJOSU' THEN 0
    WHEN 'g45ujP0td6nw' THEN 1
    WHEN 'v83f15lALyFs' THEN 2
    END AS sor FROM mytable
) xDerived
where sor is not null;
```

Results:

```
+------+--------------+------+------+
| cola | colb         | colc | sor  |
+------+--------------+------+------+
|    9 | 6kHcnevOJOSU |    1 |    0 |
|    3 | v83f15lALyFs |    1 |    2 |
|    3 | g45ujP0td6nw |    1 |    1 |
+------+--------------+------+------+
```

In Option 1, `sor` is not available in the `where` clause yet.

In Option 2, the derived table `xDerived` cleanses the use of `sor` by the outer wrapper.